# WinSock2: connect() delivers 'connection refused'

Tags: c++, networking, winsock2

I have been trying to get a simple SFTP program working with code from [this](https://www.libssh2.org/examples/sftp_write.html) website, but I have not been able to get it to even send out data without it returning error code 10061 (WSAECONNREFUSED). I have tried using Wireshark on the active interface with all firewalls disabled, but it didn't say anything was being sent to the address I gave (ex: 72.196.212.127). However, when I give it a local address like 192.168.1.101, it gives error code 10060 (WSAETIMEDOUT), still not sending out any data on the network. I am able to connect to the target machine on both address with software like Putty and WinSCP and ping it on the command prompt.

Here is the relevant part of my connection method:

```cpp
// Open socket
WSADATA data;
int err = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &data);
if (err != 0) return "ERROR: Failed to initialize WSA";

sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
struct sockaddr_in sin;
sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
sin.sin_port = htons(port);
sin.sin_addr.s_addr = to_uint32_t(ip);

if (net::connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*) &sin, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) != 0) return "ERROR: Could not connect to host. Code: " + std::to_string(WSAGetLastError());
```

The variable `port` is an integer (value = 22), with `ip` being a string (192.168.1.101 or 72.196.212.127). This function returns the "Could not connect to host" error. No other errors occur.

Here is the `to_uint32_t` method:

```cpp
std::uint32_t to_uint32_t(const std::string& ip_address)
{
    const unsigned bits_per_term = 8;
    const unsigned num_terms = 4;

    std::istringstream ip(ip_address);
    uint32_t packed = 0;

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < num_terms; ++i)
    {
        unsigned term;
        ip >> term;
        ip.ignore();

        packed += term << (bits_per_term * (num_terms - i - 1));
    }

    return packed;
}
```

Comment: You can't get a connection refusal without sending out a connection request. Fix your title.

Comment: Instead of this:  `sin.sin_addr.s_addr = to_uint32_t(ip);`, invoke this `inet_pton(AF_INET, ip, &sin.sin_addr);`  You likely need to `#include<WS2tcpip.h>` to get the `inet_pton` function.

Comment: @user207421 if i am not mistaken, a connection request is sent out by the connect method, which it is not doing. I am just getting nothing.

Comment: @selbie That did it!

Comment: Read what I wrote. It *is* sending out a connection request, and the connection refusal is the proof. That's the response from the target server, telling you nothing is listening  at the target port.

Answer (score 0):

@selbie pointed out that I was not using the correct function for resolving the IP. To fix my code, I just switched `sin.sin_addr.s_addr = to_uint32_t(ip);` to `inet_pton(AF_INET, ip, &sin.sin_addr);`.

Comment: The fundamental issue is that your to_uint32_t function is forgetting to invoke `htonl`.  But you really don't need to be implementing that function anyway given the availability of `inet_pton` and similar calls.